# Como saber que botón fue presionado VB

Tags: vb.net

Tengo un problema que espero me puedan orientar un poco.

Yo creo DINÁMICAMENTE `n` cantidad de botones en un formulario de Visual Basic según el cliente necesite.

Pueden ser 5 o pueden ser 120+.

Código de cómo los creo dinámicamente:
[image: Código VB]

```
Lbl = New Label
Lbl.Text = TextoLbl
x = EspaciadoX
y = EspaciadoY
Lbl.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(x, y)
Lbl.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
Lbl.AutoSize = True
Lbl.Cursor = Cursors.Hand
Lbl.Name = (Convert.ToString("Lbl" & InstalacionV & (0 + i)))
Lbl.Font = New Font("Goudy Old Style", 14, FontStyle.Regular)
Gb.Controls.Add(Lbl)
```

Mi problema es que no he podido crear el evento `Click` para cada botón, o al menos saber que botón se cliqueo.

Por ejemplo el cliente cliquea "Botón # 7". 
¿Como puedo saber que botón cliqueo?

OJO!
He visto ejemplos con sender y asi, pero al ser el botón creado dináamicamente me da error ya que esos métodos que he visto me piden el nombre del botón y en ese momento los botones no existen.

Comment: En el código que expones, no se está creando ningún botón dinámicamente, se están creando labels. Pulsa en [edit] y añade el código que realmente está creando los botones.

Comment: En que lenguajes??? porque en todos los que señalaste, lo que queres hacer se maneja muy pero muy diferente.

Comment: Los labels los ocupo como botones Pikoh, y ellos también pueden tener el evento OnClick.

Comment: Ahí está él código gbianchi, Visual Basic. No se de que estás hablando porque ese código me funciona perfecto para crearlos dinámicamente.

Comment: No edites mi respuesta. Si tenes mas dudas, comentalas y tratamos de resolverla. El evento no se pasa como lo pasaste, se pasa como lo marque yo.

Comment: Si, lo siento. Despues entendi como te tenia que responder. Casi no uso Stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tu label le tenes que pasar un evento que se va a ejecutar cuando se haga click

```
LB.Click += TUEVENTO
```

Tene en cuenta que ese evento tiene que respetar el tipo de firma para un evento click

```
protected void TUEVENTO(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Para saber que label se preciono, podrias usar la propiedad tag del mismo para guardar un valor ahi (puede ser un objeto) y luego recuperarla.

De esta forma, Podrias agregar a la creación del label algo asi:

```
Lbl.tag = "label1"
```

Y en el evento click hacer algo asi segun el label:

```
Label lbl = sender as Label
If lbl.tag = "label1" Then
   'tu codigo
End If
```

P.D.: creo que mezcle sintaxis de c# y vb.net. avisame si es asi.

Answer (score 0):

podrias hacer algo como esto:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    MsgBox("boton presionado")
End Sub
```

para mas detalle te sugiero revisar: [Eventos Button vb.net](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vb.net/vb.net_button.htm)

Comment: No puedo utilizar eso porque el "Button1" no existe aún, sino hasta que se inicia el programa ya que es creado dinamicamente. Al poner eso me dice algo como que Button1 no existe o no esta declarado.